# Should a class-member using-declaration with a dependent qualified-id be a dependent name?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, using-declaration, dependent-name

Draft N3337 of the C++11 standard states in `[namespace.udecl]`

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.
>
> Every using-declaration is a declaration and a member-declaration and so can be used in a class definition.
>
> In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, the nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of the
>   class being defined.

This is generally used to make a protected typedef within a base-class public in the derived class, as in the following example, which compiles successfully in the latest version of Clang:

```
struct A
{
protected:
    typedef int Type;
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::Type;
};

B::Type x;
```

The using-declaration can refer to a template class. This compiles:

```
struct A
{
protected:
    template<typename T>
    struct Type
    {
    };
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::Type;
};

B::Type<int> x;
```

It's also possible to refer to a template in a dependent base-class. The following compiles successfully (with the typedef commented.)

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
protected:
    template<typename U>
    struct Type
    {
    };
};


template<typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    using /* typename */ A<T>::Type; // A<T> is dependent, typename required?
    // typedef Type<int> IntType; // error: unknown type name 'Type'
};

B<int>::Type<int> x;
```

Uncommenting the `typename` causes an error when instantiating `B<int>`: "error: 'typename' keyword used on a non-type".

Uncommenting the typedef causes an error when parsing `B` before its first instantiation. I'm guessing this is because the compiler does not treat `Type` as a dependent type-name.

The last paragraph of `[namespace.udecl]` suggests that using-declarations may specify dependent names, and that the `typename` keyword must be used in order to disambiguate further usage of the name introduced:

> If a using-declaration uses the keyword typename and specifies a dependent name (14.6.2), the name introduced
>   by the using-declaration is treated as a typedef-name

My reading of `[temp.dep]` suggests that `A<T>::Type` is a dependent name. It follows logically that the name introduced by the using-declaration should also be dependent, but `[temp.dep]` does not explicitly mention the case of a dependent using-declaration. Am I missing something?

Comment: 7.3.3p5: "*A using-declaration shall not name a template-id*"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Type` is not a class, but a class template. You can do the following (this way you tell the compiler that `Type` is a class template in scope of `B`):

```
template<typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    using A<T>::Type;
    typedef typename B::template Type<int> IntType;
};
```

Actually, in your second example in order to write `typedef` for `IntType` you'd have to do the same.

Comment: As Anton pointed out (before editing the answer) the complication is that the using-declaration syntax does not provide a way to specify that a dependent name is a template. Subsequent use of the dependent name `Type` within `B` cannot know that it is a template, so `Type<int>` cannot be parsed.

Comment: That's a good example of a seemingly valid usage of a dependent using-declaration. It seems safe to assume that dependent using-declarations introduce dependent names.

Comment: According to [temp.dep.type], The additional qualifying `B::` makes `Type` into a "member of an unknown specialization": `B::Type<int>` names a dependent type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a class-member using-declaration with a dependent qualified-id introduces a dependent name.

> [namespace.udecl]
>
> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.

If the name introduced is dependent, it stays dependent - I can find nothing to suggest otherwise.

However, the using-declaration syntax does not provide a way to specify that a dependent name is a template. Subsequent references to the dependent name `Type` within `B` may or may not refer to a template, so `Type<int>` cannot be parsed.

The following example demonstrates valid usage of a dependent using-declaration.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
protected:
    struct Type
    {
        typedef int M;
    };
};


template<typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    using typename A<T>::Type;
    typedef typename Type::M Type2;
};

B<int>::Type2 x;
```